# Joint optimization for three variables that are not separable

Tags: optimization

I am looking for a way to optimize F(x,y,z) = f(x) + g(x,y,z) + h(x,y,z) with respect to three vectors x,y,z to where f, g, h are given by

1. f(x) = ||d – Px||^2_2
2. g(x,y,z) = a*||z – B(y)x ||^2_2
3. h(x,y,z) = b*||Ax + B(y)u +z||^2_2

**Knowns for this problem:** vector d, square matrix (diagonal but rank-deficient) P, square and invertible matrix A, and balancing scalars a and b

**Question** How can I solve this optimization problem through alternating approach?

As far as I know, ADMM cannot be used because x,y,z are not separable.
I am wondering if I can compute gradient w.r.t x, y, z separately by fixing the others and update alternately.

**FYI**
B(y) is a matrix which depends on y.

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.